# Combine a list of line segments into polygons

Tags: java, sorting, line, polygon

I have a series of unordered line segments.  The line segments may be independent lines or part of one of several polygons.  I'd like to go through the list and combine any line segments into a polygon and throw out any lines that do not form a closed polygon.

This is not as *trivial* as I thought at first.  Is this problem a *classic* problem that is solved already?

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with? Figuring out which lines have points in common? Figuring out when a set of lines forms a loop? Figuring out if that loop is a proper polygon with non-overlapping lines?

Comment: Also, when do you consider points to be overlapping? When they're exactly equal, or is there an epsilon "close enough" factor for comparing floating point numbers?

Comment: I will use a "close enough" factor.

Comment: I'm not worried about poorly shaped polygons.  I'm just trying to connect lines that got scrambled upon exporting them from another piece of software.  However, there can be multiple polygons.  So, I need to go through the list and make sure I don't take a single polygon and split it into two incomplete polygons.  I need to merge all polygons and accept as many as the user defines.

Answer (score 0):

Consider each line as a path defined by start point and end point. In 2D space this is then (x0, y0) and (x1, y1). Treat each point as a node in a graph and the line as a route in the graph, your problem is essentially to find out all circular (closed) path in a graph.

Thus you could solve this by a recursive traverse of the graph. The time complexity of a naive algorithm would be n * (length of the longest path in the graph) which is less than n ^ 2 for sure. I think someone could get a better algorithm but the idea is the same.

Comment: I understand the terms in general, but don't have any practical experience with graphs and efficient ways to traverse them (let alone traverse them recursively.  Can you provide a reference?  (Book, website, ...)

Comment: I should add that my problem is small enough that I don't have to worry about an extremely efficient algorithm.  The number of nodes < 500.